# matching four letter word with one arbitrary character

Tags: python, python-3.x

You are given a string str of lowercase letters. You need to count the number of times the word `doge` appears in the string. Also, the `g` in `doge` can be replaced by any letter from a-z so `dope` is also valid.

This question appeared on a website I was looking at. Since the site has no option to discuss the problem, I am asking for help here instead:

```
def doge_count(str):
    count=0
    for i in range (0,len(str)):
        if (i=="d" and i+1=="o" and i+3=="e"):
            count= count+1
    return count
```

For Input:

```
2
dog
dogedopedose
```

Your Output is:

```
0
0
```

Comment: you should never ever call your objects after built-ins (`str` in your snippet)

Comment: I've edited your title to describe your technical problem better. I hope you approve.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is actually pretty close. The only problem is that `i` is an integer, so the comparisons `i=="d" and i+1=="o" and i+3=="e"` will always be false. You would expect to get a match when `i==0`, but `0 !="d"`, ever.

The fix is to use `i` to index into `str`, as it seems you intended:

```
if str[i:i+2] == "do" and str[i+3] == "e":
```

You will also want to loop in a way that doesn't run past the end of the string:

```
for i in range(len(str) - 3):
```

A more robust solution would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). The following pattern matches the strings you want:

```
do[a-z]e
```

You can count occurrences using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
count = len(re.findall('do[a-z]e]', str))
```

Comment: It is not working it is saying string index out of range e

Comment: Updated. You need to change the range a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind your code not working is you are checking if an integer is equal to string in this line of code: `i=="d"`.

This line of code: `for i in range (0, len(str))` returns integer number from `0` to `length_of_string - 1`.

What you need to do is check if the string of `i`th position is equal to your desired stirng. like: `str[i] == "d"`

This would be the correct version of your code in your logic:

```
def doge_count(str):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(str)-3):
        if str[i] == "d" and str[i+1] == "o" and str[i+3] == "e":
            count = count+1
    return count


print(doge_count('dog'))
print(doge_count('dogedopedose'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [s[i:i+4] for i in range(len(s)-3) if s[i:i+2]=='do' and s[i+3]=='e']
['doge', 'dope', 'dose']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_patterns='do[a-z]e'
phrase = 'this is doze but Doze again dore then dofe'
list_matches = re.findall(test_patterns,phrase.lower())
print('The number of d(any alphabet)ze : {frequency}'.format(frequency=len(list_matches)))
```

**FindAll matches of the pattern int he list then get the count of the list and you will get the number of doge or dofe or any such**

Answer (score -1):

def doge_count(str):
i=0
count= 0
for i in range(0,len(str)-3):
if str[i]=="d" and str[i+1]=='o' and str[i+3]=='e' :
count=count+1
return count

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).